# how to change Amamon RDS mysql.slow_log table's engine to innodb

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

mysql.slow_log table default engine is CSV, CSV engine have no index;
when data size to very big ，this engine performance is very slow；

how to change Amamon RDS mysql.slow_log table's engine to innodb

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you cannot do that. Long answer is that as MySQL documentation on [log destinations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/log-destinations.html) says:

> The log tables can be altered to use the MyISAM storage engine. You cannot use ALTER TABLE to alter a log table that is in use. The log must be disabled first. **No engines other than CSV or MyISAM are legal for the log tables.**
>
> To disable logging so that you can alter (or drop) a log table, you can use the following strategy. The example uses the general query log; the procedure for the slow query log is similar but uses the slow_log table and slow_query_log system variable.
>
> ```
> SET @old_log_state = @@global.general_log;
> SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
> ALTER TABLE mysql.general_log ENGINE = MyISAM;
> SET GLOBAL general_log = @old_log_state;
> ```

Obviously, you may try to change the table engine to innodb to see if the restriction has been lifted in the amazon version, but do that only in a test environment.